# Android Can't Find Class Error When Including Library Project

Tags: android

My app consists of the following projects.

1. TheApp project
2. Android LibA
3. Android LibB

   - LibB is a marked library.
   - LibA includes LibB as a project
   - LibA exports LibB.
   - LibA is marked as a library.
   - TheApp includes LibA as a project.
   - TheApp adds LibA as a Library.
   - TheApp exports LibA so in theory the classes of LibA should be available at runtime.
   - TheApp crashes at runntime because the class in LibA cannot be found?

What can't TheApp see the class in LibA. It compiles just fine.

Comment: Have you made it a runtime dependency? Is this Eclipse or IntelliJ?

Comment: This is eclipse.  the app complains when I try to instantiate a class from LibA.

Comment: I have set the library as a dependency. I have also put it in exports.

Comment: Please post the exception stack trace. Which class cannot be found ? `R` ? A class belonging to lib A ?

Comment: It does it for any class in LibA that reference LibB.